# Odd behavior of plotting in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I would like to know if the behavior of the following code is expected.
The first figure (Series) is saved as I would expect. The second (DataFrame) is not.
If this is not a bug, how can I achieve my (obvious) goal?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
pd.Series(np.random.randn(100)).plot()
fig.savefig('c:\\temp\\plt_series.png')

fig = plt.figure()
pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,2)).plot()
fig.savefig('c:\\temp\\plt_df.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

After saving the figure, close the current plot using `plt.close()` to close the current figure, otherwise the old one is still active even if the next plot is being generated. You can also use `plt.close('all')` to be sure all open figures are closed.